# How to incrementally Update Aurora RDS with new code from git?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I need to have Database deployed via sourcecontrol.

These are the steps:
1. Consider that the primary key is in old state in AWS Aurora schema
2. make a change to PK in git : This is the new expected value
3. check-in code : code based configuration
4. verify that primary keys are restored to correct state - Automatic upgrade via Jenkins

There is no man in the middle in the above workflow.

How do we achieve CI/CD from sourcecontrol to Amazon Aurora Relational Database Service?
Are there any tools that are available to achieve this Continuous Integration workflow?

I have tried utilities like Redgate, mysqldbcompare, mysqldiff. All of them are lacking some of the automation.

We need to have comparison between source folder to target schema. We also need to have fully runnable SQL script generated from the CLI. The target database schema in AWS Aurora would already have some objects, tables, indices and stored procedures.

Any suggestions? Where can I start?
Thank you
bala